# Class.designer.cs is changing every time I open it

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, user-controls, .net-3.5

So I'm having a silly little issue that I'm hoping will be an easy fix.

So I have a custom user control, which basically just consists of a tab control and a tab (mostly just used as a drawing board for designing the tab).
Today I moved my project from VS2008-.net3.5 to VS2010-.net4.0 and for the most part everything seems perfect, except this one custom user control.

Every time I open it in the designer, it opens with a * next to it's name. And if I save it, close the page in VS then open it again, it's back!

I compared a before and after, and it's doing silly little things like setting my SplitContainer SplitterDistance to random lengths, and rearranges the order the controls are defined in the designer.cs. It's really annoying because it prompts to save every time it get's opened and screws with source control. And the positioning it keeps setting it to is off and pushes the controls a few pixels off the side of the screen.

I tried manually setting the slitter distance so there was lots of room everywhere, but it does the same thing every time it's opened.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Wright

Comment: A side effect of the control performing layout when it gets loaded at design time.  May be dpi related.  I have yet to see a question about it that documented *exactly* what was changed and how the machine on which this control was first created was different.

Comment: But you'd think that once saved it would be okay, especially in the same instance of VS. Seems so strange that you can just close the tab and then re-open the control and the designer gets altered and everything's shifted.

Comment: Interesting. I have a form with a `TableLayoutPanel` with a row that alters its height every time I open the form in VS 2010. I just put it down to one of those annoying bugs that I had to put up with. Perhaps a good answer to your question will shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a similar problem recently, I tracked it down to the setting up of event handlers in the designer generated "InitializeComponent" method.

I had event handling on SizeChanged events which after much experimentation I figured out was the cause of the issue. So whenever there was a line in InitializeComponent of the form

someControl.SomeEvent += MyEventHandler

I moved it out into the constructor, just after the call to InitializeComponent.